# Can't understand thevenin equivalent resistance

Tags: thevenin

[image]

In this case, why (R2 R1) and (R3) is parallel?

[image]

What is the difference between this one? I'm really confused.

Comment: "why (R2 R1) and (R3) is parallel?" ... Because they're in parallel. The top terminal of R3 is connected to the same node as one terminal of R1, and the other terminal of R3 is connected to the same node as one terminal of R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it help to re-draw the circuit like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f470lN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because that's exactly the same circuit you posted, just moving some of the symbols around.

Answer (score 3):

The series or parallel changes depending upon the presence of nodes. The series and parallel is determined by the flow of current. Refer the pic 
[image]

here the current is getting separated as I1 and I2 if you connect the load otherwise the nodes are considered as series

[image]

here the current flows in the loop so current remains same throughout the circuit

Comment: Great explanation with the diagrams

Answer (score 1):

When you break the circuit, remember that your looking "into" the circuit from where you broke it.  Thus, you are coming in from the right in your diagram and that is why R1 and R2 are in series and in parallel with R3.

As explained in the previous post by Honeybee, it is due to how the  current flows, (sum of all currents into node==0) but this is easily visualized when doing thevenin equivalent circuits if you look "in" from where you broke the circuit.